# Getting Message from application: Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters= (RuntimeError) error while running production mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, ruby-on-rails-5

Hi I am trying to run the rails app inside a docker in production mode. it is throwing below error.

```
Message from application: Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters= (RuntimeError)
```

Because of this my application server is not started and i am getting error page.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM docker.aws.com:443/consumertech/ruby-nginx-lua-anti-scrape:latest

# copy app source
RUN mkdir -p /data/app/my-app
RUN mkdir -p /data/app/my-app/log
RUN mkdir -p /data/app/my-app/tmp

RUN touch /data/app/my-app/dockerized
WORKDIR /data/app/my-app

ARG rails_env

ENV BUILD_ENV $rails_env

COPY . /data/app/my-app
RUN gem install bundler

RUN bundle install --with="production development test"
RUN RAILS_ENV=development bundle exec rake assets:precompile


ENV RAILS_ENV $rails_env
ENV NEW_RELIC_KEY "41dfc2f90fb480fbd4d2df35b77fffde68e42c74"

# unicorn
EXPOSE 3000


# need to start both unicorn and nscd
RUN echo "#!/usr/bin/env sh \n \
service nscd start \n \
unicorn -c ./config/unicorn.rb -E ${RAILS_ENV} -p 3000 \n \
bundle exec passenger start -p 3000 \

" > go.sh


RUN chmod 0755 go.sh

CMD ["./go.sh"]
```

Comment: show your docker file

Comment: @PratheeshM Added docker file for refrence do you need stacktrace?

Comment: have you used docker-compose

Comment: @PratheeshM I build the docker image with tag and manually run the using "docker run -p 3000:3000 -e RAILS_ENV=production docker.aws.com:443/consumertech/myapp:tag"

Answer (score 12):

On the `config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb` find a line that includes `raise_on_unfiltered_parameters` and delete it.

Answer (score 1):

For some other cases, you might just have to look into `application.rb` and delete the line `config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters = true`.