# Puma caught this error: Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I am learning Ruby on Rails with Michael Hartl's book `Ruby on Rails™ Tutorial: Learn Web Development with Rails, Fourth Edition`. I got the error message when trying the `toy_app`. Does anyone know what's wrong?

```
Puma caught this error: Invalid option key: raise_on_unfiltered_parameters= (RuntimeError)
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:59:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54:in `each'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/railtie.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
.gem/ruby/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
.gem/ruby/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `execute_hook'
.gem/ruby/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
.gem/ruby/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `each'
.gem/ruby/gems/activesupport-5.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:263:in `<class:Base>'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:164:in `<module:ActionController>'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_controller/base.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:77:in `ext'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:33:in `match?'
.gem/ruby/gems/actionpack-5.0.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:130:in `call'
.gem/ruby/gems/rack-2.0.5/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
.gem/ruby/gems/railties-5.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:224:in `call'
.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:569:in `handle_request'
.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'
.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/server.rb:271:in `block in run'
.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `call'
.gem/ruby/gems/puma-3.4.0/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:114:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Update: commenting out `raise_on_unfiltered_parameters` resolves the issue.

Comment: Please show the controller code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting Message from application: Invalid option key: raise\_on\_unfiltered\_parameters= (RuntimeError) error while running production mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46905738/getting-message-from-application-invalid-option-key-raise-on-unfiltered-parame)

Comment: @mahemoff the controller codes are posted

Comment: @mahemoff the user code is generated with `rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string` followed by `rails db:migrate`

Comment: @anothermh my problem is resolved by commenting out raise_on_unfiltered_parameters. How can I delete my post?

Comment: @user2196452 You should have a "delete" option under your post (just below the tags). However, it would be more helpful to others if you leave an answer based on what you did ie comment out the raise_on_unfiltered_paramteters (and then accept your own answer).

Answer (score 3):

I was having this same issue and thi was how i solved it:
go to the

> config/initializers/new_framework_defaults.rb

and comment or delete this line of code:

```
 Rails.application.config.action_controller.raise_on_unfiltered_parameters = true
```

i hope this helps